# Is there any API for knowing the SMS tracking in Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, sms

Please tell me is there any API for knowing the incoming sms status, outgoing sms status, reading sms status, delete sms status in Windows Phone 7?

Answer (score 4):

By 'status', in this context, I assume you mean you want to handle these events from your app? No, in the current SDK, you can't get access to the user's text messages. You can set up and text message, but there's currently no way to interact directly with existing messages or handling incoming/outgoing events.